# Удалениe класса элемента jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, кто может подскажите пожалуйста. Есть следущий код.

```
<img src="url" class="2-5 none(это класс display:none)" />
<div id="test">
<a href="#" class="2-5">Ссылка</a>
</div>
```

как при клике на ссылку убирать этот класс none?
Думал сделать так:

```
$("#test").children("a").click(function () {
    $(this)
    return false;
});
```

А дальше не понимаю что содержится в этом this? Как найти элемент img s тем же классом? В принципе всем кодом могу манипулировать менять классы и id и т.д Подскажите, как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: Начнём с того, что ```Названия классов могут начинаться только с буквы или подчеркивания```, ну а достучаться можно без классов: `$(this).parent().prev('img')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```js
$('a.2-5').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var img = $('img.2-5');
  
  if(!img.hasClass('none')){
    img.addClass('none');
  }else {
    img.removeClass('none');
    
  }
});
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="url" class="2-5 none" />

  <div id="test">
  <a href="#" class="2-5">Ссылка</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавьте `toggle` для картинки, на действие `onclick` по ссылке.

***Пример:***

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="url" class="the-same-image" />
<div id="test">
<a href="#" class="2-5" onclick="$('.the-same-image').toggle()">Ссылка</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем огромное спасибо за ответы!) но сделал по другому.. нужно было сделать:
Главное изображение - маленькие превью - при клике замена главного на большое из превью. Получилось так:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Заголовок</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="Главная картинка первоначальная" id="img">
    <a href="http://site.ru/image_big.jpg" class="url_full"><img src="http://site.ru/image_small.jpg" class="img_prew"></a>
    <a href="URL большого изображения" class="url_full"><img src="URL маленького изображения" class="img_prew"></a>
    <a href="URL большого изображения" class="url_full"><img src="URL маленького изображения" class="img_prew"></a>
    <a href="URL большого изображения" class="url_full"><img src="URL маленького изображения" class="img_prew"></a>
    <a href="URL большого изображения" class="url_full"><img src="URL маленького изображения" class="img_prew"></a>
    <script>
    $(".url_full").click(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#img").attr('src', url);
    return false;
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```